# Show that if $X_1, X_2,...,X_{11}$ are random variables, and $\operatorname{corr}(X_i,X_j) = r$ for $ i\neq j$ , then show $r \geq -1/10$

Tags: probability, covariance, correlation

$\DeclareMathOperator{\corr}{\mathsf{corr}}$Show that if $X_1, X_2,...,X_{11}$ are random variables, and $\corr(X_i,X_j) = r, i\neq j$ , then show $r \geq -1/10$.

I think I need to do this with induction for $n$, so if $X_1, X_2,...,X_{n}$ are random variables, and $\corr(X_i,X_j) = r$ for $i\neq j$ , then  $r \geq -1/(n-1)$. I got the first step, when $n = 2$ it's saying if $X_1,X_2$ are random variables, then $\corr(X_1,X_2)\geq -1$, which is true because $|\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2)| = |E[(X_1 - E(X_1))(X_2 -E(X_2))]| \leq  D(X_1)D(X_2)$, where $D$ is the variance, so $|\corr(X_1,X_2)| \leq 1 \implies \corr(X_1,X_2)\geq -1$.
I can't go any further when I assume it's true for $n-1$.

Comment: Hint: assume wlog that $\mathrm{var}\left( X_i\right) =1$ and use the fact $\mathrm{var}\left(\sum_i X_i\right) \ge 0$.

Comment: Why can we assume that their variance is all equal wlog?

Comment: Because the question is about correlation coefficients = covariances of standardized rv's.

Answer (score 2):

No need for induction. First, show that
$$
\mathbb{V} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right ) = n \sigma^2 + n(n-1) r \sigma^2
$$
then, combine this with the fact that variance is non-negative

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer

Comment: There is no assumption that $\mathrm{var}(X_i) = \sigma^2$.